# With \Mail::send can not set title

Tags: laravel, email

In Laravel 6 I send email with \Mail::send (DataGrip in .env) and I recieve the email, can not set title.
is is the same as content of the email.
I do as :

```
    $data = array ( // That is not applied
        'title' => 'Title 234',
        'bodyMessage' => $message_text,
        'sender_username' => $name,
        'sender_email' => $email,
        'site_name' => $site_name,
    );

    \Mail::send ( 'emails/contact_us', $data, function ($message) use($data, $donotreply_email, $contact_us_email) {
        $message->from ( $donotreply_email, 'Support of ' . $data['site_name'] );
        $message->to ( $contact_us_email )->subject ( $data['bodyMessage'] );
```

//            $message->title('Message 34 Title'); // If to uncomment it it does not work too.
        } );

Which is valid way ?

Thanks!

Comment: ->subject ($data['bodyMessage'] ? $data['bodyMessage'] : 'If this subject get means your bodyMessage empty' )

Comment: try above condition i thought you $message_text is going empty that why subject is not set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to set a mail title it means mail `subject`. So set subject instead of title.

```
$message->subject('Message 34 Title');
```